# Is it mandatory to implement concrete aspect in aspectJ

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I am running a HelloWorld project using load time weaving (LTW) in aspectJ. I had defined abstract aspect only. I had not defined concrete aspect but mentioned `"name"` attribute of `<concrete-aspect>` as `main.java.aop.helloworld.MyHelloWorldAspect` in the aop.xml as below:

```
<concrete-aspect name="main.java.aop.helloworld.MyHelloWorldAspect"
        extends="main.java.aop.helloworld.HelloWorldAspect">
        <pointcut name="helloWorld"
            expression="execution(public static void HelloWorld.say*(..))" />
    </concrete-aspect>
```

I could run the application fine and getting the desired result. But, below line is printed to define the concrete aspect.

```
[URLClassLoader@ddc3fe] info define aspect main.java.aop.helloworld.MyHelloWorldAspect
```

I am wondering whether concrete class implementation is mandatory or not as it prints a INFO message to define concrete aspect. Also, weaving and applying aspect and advice works fine as per the below INFO message.

```
[URLClassLoader@ddc3fe] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(void main.java.aop.helloworld.HelloWorld.say(java.lang.String))' in Type 'main.java.aop.helloworld.HelloWorld' (HelloWorld.java:5) advised by before advice from 'main.java.aop.helloworld.MyHelloWorldAspect' (HelloWorldAspect.java)
```

Could anyone explain whether concrete class implementation is mandatory or not. If not required, then please help me in understanding how it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't provide a concrete aspect then the advice in the abstract aspect will not apply. Compile this:

```
class C {}
abstract aspect X { before():staticinitialization(C) {}}
```

and the advice in X will not apply to C. Remove the `abstract` or provide a concrete sub-aspect of X and it will apply. However, that is only true for advice - any static crosscutting in the abstract aspect *will* apply, for example and method or field inter type declaration.

You have two options for the concrete aspect - either code or XML, and you are going the XML route which is fine. I think the first (badly worded) info message you show is telling you that the system is defining the concrete aspect according to your spec, not that you need to.